# Android: Adding a view in onDraw() method calls it repeatedly

Tags: android, android-view, viewgroup

I am creating an Android application. I want that when my `Parent` is ready to be drawn, it collects its children's views from a function. I am doing it because my children's views are being refreshed dynamically. On each refresh, I am invalidating my Parent's layout.

```
class Parent extends RelativeLayout
{
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        View view = getComposeView();
        // create layoutparams depending upon scroll/zoom level of parent
        addView(view, layoutparams);
    }

}

// In some other class
View getComposeView()
{
     //
     return view;
}

void refreshViews(View newView)
{
    setComposeView(newView);
    getParent().invalidate();
}
```

I observed that calling `addView` in the `onDraw` method triggers `onDraw` repeatedly. Is there a way I can add my view to `Parent` in its `onDraw` method? The reason I wanted to add it in `onDraw` is because when I scroll/zoom my `Parent`, it automatically calculates updated layout parameters of my child view in its `onDraw` method